# What happens when you 'create' an item on the OpenSea app?

Tags: solidity, web3js, nft

Very noobie here. I'm sorry,

Does anybody know what happens on OpenSea when you actually CREATE an item?

I know it doesn't mint one but what it does? (As it signs a transaction tho).

I've been trying for weeks to understand the "gasless" proxy thing they have but I don't know how they actually transfer an NFT to your Wallet, even if it's not minted.

I also managed to deploy and mint a Creature with the example contract (open sea creatures, https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures) but how can I let Users mint their own item on this factory contract?